# What can the Haskell package category-extras be used for?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, functional-programming, ct.category-theory

See [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras). Has anyone attempted to use this to verify category theoretic proofs? Given the relationship between categories and [graphs](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver), are there some applications with respect to graph algorithms? What other possible uses are there for this package and those associated with it?

I realize this is a broad, open-ended question, which may not be entirely appropriate for Stack Exchange. A better place to post this question could also be a helpful answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that that package could be used for that but it seems like this paper might help you verify category theoretic proofs http://www.nuprl.org/documents/Kreitz/06ijcar-categories.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library is not especially useful for category-theoretic proofs, since Haskell's typechecking is not sufficient to verify that the constructions satisfy the required properties. Surprisingly enough ;), it's actually intended to be used for writing Haskell programs. You are best off asking on the [Haskell-cafe mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/haskell-cafe) for examples.